# About the nature of time

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time

Why do we relate time to physical things? Why just we don’t assume a universal non physical time? Why isn’t  a second a second everywhere in the universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we relate time to physical things? Why just we don’t assume a universal non physical time?

Because physics is the study of physical things. A non physical time would be useless in physics.

> Why isn’t a second a second everywhere in the universe?

A second is a second everywhere in the universe. That is a direct consequence of the equivalence principle.

Be aware that the second is defined as a unit of proper time, not coordinate time. So the fact that there is gravitational time dilation does not contradict the above. Gravitational time dilation is the ratio of coordinate time and proper time. So the coordinate time is the non-physical time that can change, not the proper time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do elementary particles experience gravitational time dilation and what about particles with no size?

Comment: @Akash I would say that the time that is “experienced” is proper time. Regardless of the size of an object, there is some coordinate dependent relationship between proper time and coordinate time, which we call time dilation. But I wouldn’t say that it is something that is “experienced”. I would reserve that term for proper time

Answer (score 0):

Akash, here is what might be an easier way to understand this.

A second is indeed a second everywhere- but if you are moving very fast in relation to the thing you are observing, you will observe time passing more slowly for that object than it does for you. This muddles up what we observe as a "second", and is because of special relativity. And if you are very far away from it, then you are not seeing it as it *is*- you are seeing it as it *was*. That's because it takes time for light to travel.

Physicists have to be very careful is assessing time durations and simultaneity because of these effects. Fortunately, Einstein did the necessary math for us over 100 years ago, which has been taught ever since to beginner physicists.

Comment: I am actually a student of B.Pharmacy interested in physics. Thanks for your answer. Now I understand why space and time are one thing and not two. If we assume time to be separate from space and if space is assumed to be constant and non changing and time is moving as usual then by definition by time, time should cause time(time is a measure of change) and in this case other theories won’t work.